# Have a column with the lowest possible next value (self-joining a table)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014, cross-apply

I am looking for a way to get the lowest next value in a sequence. Basically, I have a dataset of Dates and I want it to return the next day unless it's the latest date in the database, then I want it to return this instead.

My current query looks like this and almost works - of course up to the point where I want the latest possible value instead of the next one:

```
SELECT
  a.date,
  a.key,
  a.description,
  b.date NextDate
FROM
  my_table a
  CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1
  b.date
FROM
  my_table b
WHERE
  a.key = b.key AND
  a.date < b.date) b
```

Sample data:

```
+----------+-----+-------------+
|   date   | key | description |
+----------+-----+-------------+
| 20170101 | atx | xxx         |
| 20161228 | hfn | xxx         |
| 20161222 | ktn | xxx         |
| 20161214 | yqe | xxx         |
| 20161204 | olp | xxx         |
| 20161122 | bux | xxx         |
+----------+-----+-------------+
```

What the result should look like:

```
+----------+-----+-------------+----------+
|   date   | key | description | NextDate |
+----------+-----+-------------+----------+
| 20170101 | atx | xxx         | 20170101 |
| 20161228 | hfn | xxx         | 20170101 |
| 20161222 | ktn | xxx         | 20161228 |
| 20161214 | yqe | xxx         | 20161222 |
| 20161204 | olp | xxx         | 20161214 |
| 20161122 | bux | xxx         | 20161204 |
+----------+-----+-------------+----------+
```

Comment: You forgot the `ORDER BY` clause in the `CROSS APPLY` query.

Comment: Which version of sql server you are using

Comment: better specified it to 2014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `case` expression to do this.

```
SELECT
  a.date,
  a.key,
  a.description,
  case when date = max(a.date) over() then date
  else (select min(date) from mytable b where a.date < b.date)  end as NextDate
FROM
  my_table a
```

Comment: This might have been my poor choice of data but the data is in most cases not strictly chronological. I ammend my sample data.

Comment: No, because `GetDate()` returns the current date. I changed my sample data to better reflect what I am after.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lag` on date column

```
select t.*,
    lag(date, 1, date) over (order by date desc) nextdate
from 
(SELECT
  a.date,
  a.key,
  a.description,
  b.date NextDate
FROM
  my_table a
  CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1
  b.date
FROM
  my_table b
WHERE
  a.key = b.key AND
  a.date < b.date) b) t
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want:

```
select a.*,
       coalesce(lead(date) over (order by date),
                max(date) over ()
               )
from my_table a;
```

Comment: This simply gives me the same date for every column.

Comment: @Spurious . . . This should not give the same date for every column.  It should have the next date if there is one and the maximum date if there is none.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
;with cte as
(
SELECT [DATE] = Cast([date] AS DATE),
       [key],
       [description],
       Lag([date])OVER(ORDER BY  Cast([date] AS DATE) DESC) AS prev_date
FROM   ( VALUES ('20170101','atx','xxx'),
                ('20161228','hfn','xxx'),
                ('20161222','ktn','xxx'),
                ('20161214','yqe','xxx'),
                ('20161204','olp','xxx'),
                ('20161122','bux','xxx')) tc ([date], [key], [description])
)
SELECT [date],
       [Key],
       [Description],
       NextDate = Iif([date] < prev_date, prev_date, [date])
FROM   cte
```

**Result :**

```
+------------+-----+-------------+------------+
|    date    | Key | Description |  NextDate  |
+------------+-----+-------------+------------+
| 2017-01-01 | atx | xxx         | 2017-01-01 |
| 2016-12-28 | hfn | xxx         | 2017-01-01 |
| 2016-12-22 | ktn | xxx         | 2016-12-28 |
| 2016-12-14 | yqe | xxx         | 2016-12-22 |
| 2016-12-04 | olp | xxx         | 2016-12-14 |
| 2016-11-22 | bux | xxx         | 2016-12-04 |
+------------+-----+-------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

If your table never has a missing date the following would work.

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE,CONVERT(CHAR(10),a.date,120))
,a.key,
,a.description,
,CASE 
    WHEN (SELECT MAX(a.date) FROM my_table a) <> AsAtDateID 
        THEN DATEADD(DAY,1,CONVERT(DATE,CONVERT(CHAR(10),a.date,120)))--This could be a select statement
    ELSE CONVERT(DATE,CONVERT(CHAR(10),a.date,120))
END 
FROM my_table a
ORDER BY Date DESC
```

Alternatively if there are missing dates then you could use a SQL statement in the CASE to get the next highest date.

```
SELECT MIN(Date) FROM my_table WHERE Date > a.Date
```

Not the most performant code, but seeing as we are talking date tables it would work. I'm sure a CTE could be used to do this as well, if you need a bit more performance
Using SQL 2008 without LEAD & LAG etc...